# Error editing MVC website

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

I tried to create a MVC website and tried to connect SQL Database with that website. While trying to edit the DB through the website I got the following error,

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVC_Sample.Models
{
    public class ThirdController : Controller
    {
        private Servion_sathiyaEntities db = new Servion_sathiyaEntities();

        //
        // GET: /Third/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.ipls.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Third/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(string id = null)
        {
            ipl ipl = db.ipls.Find(id);
            if (ipl == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(ipl);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Third/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Third/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ipl ipl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.ipls.Add(ipl);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(ipl);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Third/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(string id = null)
        {
            ipl ipl = db.ipls.Find(id);
            if (ipl == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(ipl);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Third/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(ipl ipl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(ipl).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(ipl);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Third/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(string id = null)
        {
            ipl ipl = db.ipls.Find(id);
            if (ipl == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(ipl);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Third/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {
            ipl ipl = db.ipls.Find(id);
            db.ipls.Remove(ipl);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how my controller looks. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: A 404 error is very common, so you need to show us some relevant code. What does your controller look like?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line following `ipl ipl = db.ipls.Find(id);` and check both the values of `id` and `ipl`. Your telling the action to return a 404 error if `ipl == null`